# Getting error while changing to string-array from string in text field of activity xml file in android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, string

I want to display random strings each time my android app is opened. Using stackoverflow, I was able to write a java program for getting random strings from a resource file.

```
    package com.example.krishna.quotes;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Random;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] myString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();


        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            Resources res = getResources();

            myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.quotes_array);

            String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            tv.setText(q);

    }
}
```

When I used the string type in text field of the activity xml file, the app was built without any errors.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.krishna.quotes.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string-array/quotes_array"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But since I don't want only one string to be displayed everytime I opened my app, I collected all my strings into a string-array.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="quotes_array">
        <item>@string/quote1</item>
        <item>@string/quote2</item>
        <item>@string/quote3</item>
        <item>@string/quote4</item>
        <item>@string/quote5</item>
        <item>@string/quote6</item>
        <item>@string/quote7</item>
        <item>@string/quote8</item>
        <item>@string/quote9</item>
        <item>@string/quote10</item>
        <item>@string/quote11</item>
        <item>@string/quote12</item>
        <item>@string/quote13</item>
        <item>@string/quote14</item>
        <item>@string/quote15</item>

    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Changing the text field in activity xml file gave the following error:

Error:(15, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string-array/quotes_array').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/krishna/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

The problem is with the string-array type most probably, which android studio is not able to handle. How do I overcome this problem to build my first android app? I'm quite excited to show off my app to my friends, but this small error is coming in my way. Thank you for your help. Please don't call me a noob

Comment: I think need to use `android:text="@array/quotes_array"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing

> string-array name = "quotes_array"

in your Strings.xml

use

array name="quotes_array"